# Why can't I change my close-vote reason or not close-vote anymore after retracting?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, vote-to-close

I just close-voted [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/629095/how-can-i-detect-new-files-and-add-random-number-end-of-the-file) with reason "*Needs details or clarity*".

Afterwards, I saw, that [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files%20fits) fits very well, and I would like to change my vote to "*Duplicate of ...*". But I cannot change my close reason, only retract it. But then I'm not allowed to close-vote again.

[image: Are you sure?]

So, my question is:
**Why is close-voting disallowed after retracting?** or
**Should we implement the ability to change the close-vote reason?**

As we seek to help people in the best possible way, wouldn't it be good to change your close-vote reason to the one that fits better?

Note, I don't want to discuss the close-voting for this specific question, it serves only as an example.

Comment: Some previous discussion on MSE: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction

Comment: It looks like re-casting a retracted vote is not possible in order to prevent abuse (and it is actually possible [once the "aging" period is over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200391/allow-another-close-vote-after-retraction#comment867915_200391)). The [Ability to change close reason before it gets closed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/863/410681) has been asked for several times on the main Meta; I wasn't able to spot the rationale for not implementing it (except for the implicit "it's not worth the work").